# Need C++ parser

Tags: c++, parsing, free

I need a good, stable and, maybe, easy to use C++ parser library with C/C++ interface (C is preferred).
I hear that cint is good c++ interpreter. Can I use it (or some part of it) for this purpose?
Any suggestions?

Comment: The real question is, "what is your purpose?".  For very simple tasks, cint might be helpful.  For any sophisticated analysis, you'll need the equivalent of a full C++ compiler front end (name resolution for C++ is a bitch).  For any attempt to *transform* the code you'll need tools that can round trip the source, and there are extremely few of these.

Comment: @Ira: `cint` *is* a full c++ complier...it can run in a native code generation mode as well as interpretation. Whether it is well structured for Artem needs or not, I couldn't tell you.

Comment: @dmckee: So it sounds like cint likely has full name/type resolution, and that may be enough for Artem, and it may not.  He still needs to be clear about his purpose before anybody can be clear about what a real solution for him is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See: http://clang.llvm.org/
It has both a C++ and a C interface (libclang).

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no plain C access to AST yet (and no plans to implement one).

Comment: I think it should be possible to walk through the AST through libclang. See e.g. <http://llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/Gregor-libclang.pdf>.

Comment: Thank you for answers, I'm going to test clang now. Seems, it can be the solution...

Comment: Caveat: look closely at the C++0x support, a number of cases are not dealt with yet (though if you only need the AST, things are looking bright). And of course the fact that the community is reactive is a nice bonus.

Comment: libclang is a C++ API; Plain C wrappers are rudimentary.

Answer (score 9):

C++ parsing is famously hard. AFAIK there are only three parsers that are acceptable by todays standards: EDG (widely used as a frontend in popular C++ compilers), GCC's and Microsoft's. And apparently, Microsoft has started using EDG's parser in VS2010, for Intellisense.

When you're looking at the free options, you're pretty much stuck at GCC. It can produce XML, though, so the easy part is there. (Easy by C++ parsing standards, that is)

Comment: CLang is doing quite a bit of work. Whether the missing details are too much to consider it *acceptable* or not is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: "Parses Boost" is my personal norm. And I understand that Clang isnt there yet.

Comment: @MSalters, The clang project claim to be able to compile Boost now but can only partially compile Qt so they're getting there, but I don't think I'd like to try to compile production code with it.  http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

Comment: @MSalters: There is a lot of difference between being able to produce an AST and being able to compile it. Clang parses Boost fine as far as I know.

Comment: @MSalters, Clang is not only able to parse Boost, it even passes most of its tests: http://blog.llvm.org/2010/05/clang-builds-boost.html

Comment: Clang has a modern parser that beats GCC on most c++03 disciplines that I tried it with.

Answer (score 2):

Clang is the most up-to-date and mature option, with a decent C++ API (but no plain C). Elsa is a bit out of date and unmaintained, but still a usable choice. Both could be used as libraries as well as standalone XML frontends.

Comment: "Clang currently implements all of the ISO C++ 1998 standard (including the defects addressed in the ISO C++ 2003 standard) except for 'export' (which has been removed from the C++'0x draft) and is considered a production-quality C++ compiler" Date: 2011-07-27 clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html – Grzegorz Wierzowiecki

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse C or C++ code, there are some options:
http://bellard.org/tcc/
http://students.ceid.upatras.gr/~sxanth/ncc/

If you want to create a parser using C/C++, you can try:
http://boost-spirit.com/home/
http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/ Lex and Yacc
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/patterns/article.php/c12805 Flex and Bison

Answer (score 2):

Our [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) is able to parse a variety of C++ dialects (ANSI, GCC, MSVS), automatically builds ASTs whose nodes are marked with precise source positions and are decorated with any nearby comment text, and builds a full symbol table.  (EDIT Jan 2013: the C++ front end has been able to handle C++11 for quite awhile now).

The C++ front end is built on top of our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html), generalized compiler technology for program analysis and transformation, designed to support custom tool building.  The C++ front end includes a preprocessor, in which the preprocessor directives can be expanded or not collectively or individually as appropriate for the task. It also includes full symbol construction with all the nasty Koenig lookup stuff.

DMS accepts explicit language definitions (that's how it understands C++; there are also fron ends for C, C#, Java, COBOL, and variety of other languages).  DMS provides general parsing, symbol table building, flow analysis machinery, procedural APIs for tree navigation/inspection/modification, source-to-source transformation, and AST-to-source text regeneration including the original comments, number radices, etc.  All of these capabilities are available for use by the C++ Front End.

DMS is also designed to handle the scale required for serious tasks.  Often you need not just *one* compilation unit (which is what GCC will give you at best) but access to an entire set.  DMS has been used to analyze/transform thousands of C++ compilation units, and literally tens of thousands of C compilation units (on a 25 million line application).

"Easy to use library" is an oxymoron when it comes to program manipulation tools.  The langauges themselves are complex (C++ being one of the most difficult and getting worse with C++0X) and that induces complexity in the nature of the questions you can ask and what the answers look like (e.g. "are there any template instantions that can modify local variable X in method Y in class C in any namespace N?").   The questions themselves are hard.

What you want is a library with the *necessary* complexity to let you carry off your task.  DMS has been under continuous development for the last 15 years, to provide that necessary complexity.  If you want to do serious program processing, I claim you will need that information.

As proof, DMS has been used to carry out massive automated reengineering of C++-based mission avionics software for Boeing.   I don't believe there are any other tools that can do this.  (Clang looks to be trying, but only for C++. YMMV).

Comment: This is an enterprise product; pricing depends on configuration and planned deployment. Contact the sales team.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for cint, but I heard people use [gcc-xml](http://www.gccxml.org) for this.

I have been looking for a good stand-alone library too, but haven't found any.

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling brave the links in the answer to "[is there a yacc-able C++ grammar?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html#faq-38.11)" might be helpful. Gcc-xml and clang have already been suggested and [Swig also has an XML output](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/swigxml.html) which depending on what you're trying to achieve might be relevant.

Comment: "Feeling brave" would be the wrong term. You have to feel Olympian to take on a task like a full C++ parser.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try it, but I think that best choice will be getting modules for parsing from some popular open source compiler like [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) for C++;

Maybe you'll find something interesting here http://www.nobugs.org/developer/parsingcpp/